# Replication in MySQL master-master

Tags: mysql, database

The problem is  in MySQL master-master  productivity  replication . The query from the web application performs a series of SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT operations without replication for 300-400 ms. With turn on   the replication  1200-1400 ms, which is already critical for users. If we turn off  replication, then the application works  good. Virtual machines spin on the SSD. We tried to change the parameters innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 (in my.ini) - to no avail. What could be the problem is ?

Comment: How is your replication configured?  It is through log shipping or real time replication (two phase commit)?  Replicated databases are ok on select, but slower on update and inserts.  That is to be expected as it has to write twice and you add network latency.

Comment: The replication is configured on Windows machines similar to this article: [link] (https://udhyantimilsina.com/2012/10/25/master-to-master-replication-of-mysql-server-in-windows-server-2008) . Here  are my.ini from two servers: [link] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10AQ8In-RDqvB9MByH9BDrBeRPBmB4OGZ)